# Laravel Error: Could not open input file: partisan

Tags: database, laravel, path, migration

I know there are a lot of Laravel questions mentioning 'Could not open file: artisan'. That is not my problem. Mine specifically states 'partisan'.

I'm inputting the following code in my terminal to migrate a separate database migration to be run alone.

```
php partisan migrate --path="database/migrations/third_migrations"
```

and I get the error message identified above. What is the correct syntax for running a migration that is in its own separate folder? Thanks guys.

Comment: Looks like you haven't configured partisan correctly. Do other commands with partisan work?

Comment: Sorry, but what it is - partisan?

Comment: this is my screen image - https://www.screencast.com/t/1qqJSYJSoMz

hmm, how do I get partisan to work? I don't know what partisan is that well either, i'll look it up now.

Comment: It's "artisan".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `artisan`, not `partisan`:

```
php artisan
```

You can find this PHP file in the root of the Laravel project.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan